# Java - Generate JVM ByteCode from ANTLR 4 Visitor Implementation

Tags: java, jvm, antlr4, bytecode, visitor-pattern

I am developing a language which has been implemented in Java with the help of ANTLR 4 and its Visitor Pattern. Now what I would like to do is from the implemented code in the Visitor Pattern, generate JVM Bytecode that can later be executed on a Java Virtual Machine.

So, for example, given the following code (let's say that is the language I'm creating):

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
if (a == b && c == d && a == d) {
    System.out.println("b = c");
} else {
    System.out.println("No!");
}
```

And I have the following functions implemented in Visitor Pattern of ANTLR 4 which handles the different instructions of my language(assignment, if, logical and relational comparison, etc):

```
// ...
void ifStatement(...) {
    // ...
}
// &&, ||, !
void logicalComparison(...) {
    // ...
}
// ==, !=, <=, >=, <, >
void relationalComparison(...) {
    // ...
}
//...
```

The problem I am having is that when I am generating the code for the `if` statement, I need a way to remember the position of the comparisons so I can return after generating the `else` statement, to place its position so that the jump can be possible if the conditions are not fulfilled.

What would be the best way to go about generating the Bytecode?

Comment: ASM allows you to create and use `Label` objects even before you define their actual location via `visitLabel(…)`. I don’t know the details, but the parser visitor API should support passing context information of the parent construct to the subexpression. More should not be necessary.

Comment: @Holger The problem is how do I know when to jump when processing a logical comparison statement (&&, ||, !, ...)? I would need some way to know what I am inside of an if condition and in some way save the labels for the different parts of the if statement.

Comment: As said, I don’t know what options ANTLR offers for passing context information up or down, but there must be some. Normally, compilers create a representation first, see [Abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), which is then processed for generating the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use labels, together with the `goto` bytecode. Depending on which code generation tool you are using, it could be something of the sort

```java
// Visit your condition so its result is pushed on the stack

// Create three new labels
int iflab   = ++labels; // Label to jump to if the condition was true
int elselab = ++labels; // Label to jump to if the condition was false
int donelab = ++labels; // Label to jump to once done executing either branches

generate("ifne label" + iflab);
generate("goto label" + elselab);

generate("label" + iflab + ":");
// visit the statement needing to be executed if the condition was true
generate("goto label" + donelab);

generate("label" + elselab + ":");
// visit the statement needing to be executed if the condition was false (if there is one)
generate("goto label" + donelab);

println("label" + donelab + ":");
// You are done with this statement, keep visiting the following statements.
```

This is unoptimized (too many labels created and gotos), but it should be clear. The generate method just writes bytecode to a file, I was using [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/guide.html) when writing this. It should be similar using [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) or any other JVM bytecode tool.

Comment: The problem is how do I know when to jump when processing a logical comparison statement (&&, ||, !, ...)? I would need some way to know what I am inside of an if condition and in some way save the labels for the different parts of the if statement. And what if I have nested if statements?